# Dynamically added semanctic ui checkbox / radio / rating events not firing

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

Dynamically added checkbox / radio buttons / rating elements are not firing the attached events in semantic ui. Below is the js fiddle for sample and its not all triggering the events when check box is checked i have tried both 'setting' option and onChange separately as well. nothing is working as expected.
**Javascript :**

```
$("#cbdiv").checkbox('setting', 'onChange', function() {
  alert("Changed");
});
$("#addcheckboxes").unbind();
var chkcounter = 0;
$("#addcheckboxes").bind('click', function() {
  $('#chkgrp').append("<div id='chkbx_'" + chkcounter + "class='ui checkbox'><input type='checkbox'  ></div>");
  $('#chkbx_' + chkcounter).checkbox({
    onChange: function() {
      alert('i am added. my id is : ' + $(this).attr('id'));
    }
  });
});
```

**Html**

```
<div class="field">
  <div id="cbdiv" class="ui toggle checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="confirm" name="confirmed">
    <label>Confirmed</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="addcheckboxes">Add checkboxes</button>
    <div id="chkgrp">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/tummgh41/56/)

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle,  http://jsfiddle.net/tummgh41/79/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the append statement adding wrong `id` element. After the append statement execute, if you look at your html it will look like below.

```
<div id="chkgrp">
   <div id="chkbx_" 0class="ui checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
   </div>
</div>
```

After the above code execute, you are searching for the id `chkbx_0` through jquery and try to add the onChange event for that. So it is failed. Update your append element syntax like below and it will work.

```
  $('#chkgrp').append("<div id='chkbx_" + chkcounter + "' class='ui checkbox'><input type='checkbox'  ></div>");
```

In the above code, I have closed `id` string after adding chkcounter `id='chkbx_" + chkcounter + "'`. In your earlier code you have closed the `id` string before adding the chkcounter itself `id='chkbx_'" + chkcounter + "`.

**UPDATE**

Looks like your `semantic` css have the following styles.

```
   .ui.checkbox input {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0px;
       left: 0px;
       opacity: 0;
       outline: 0px;
   }
```

Because of the above styles you are not able to see the checkboxs. If you want to see the styled checkbox then you have add the `label` to your check box and update your code like below.

```
  $('#chkgrp').append("<div id='chkbx_" + chkcounter + "' class='ui checkbox'><input type='checkbox'><label>test</label></div>");
```

Also I have noticed that you are trying to get the ID of the element using `$(this).attr('id')`. This statement will give the output `undefined`, because the checkbox does not have any attribute called `id`. I hope you are trying to get the id `chkbx_0`. In that case you have to add your code like below.

```
  $(this).parent().attr('id');
```

I have updated your fiddle with all the above changes and you can see the demo [**here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/tummgh41/89/)

Comment: I have updated the script but not working as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/tummgh41/79/

Answer (score 1):

In checkbox code ID name is not set properly that's is the reason. You can see below working code

```
$("#addcheckboxes").bind('click', function() {
   chkcounter++; // set counter increment
   $('#chkgrp').append("<div id='chkbx_"+chkcounter+"' class='ui checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxval[]' id='checkbox_id_"+chkcounter+"'  ></div>"); 
   $('#chkbx_'+chkcounter).checkbox({onChange:function(){alert('i am added. my id is : '+$(this).attr('id'));}});
});
```

Hope this will help you.